# Call AppDelegate Method from Class

Tags: iphone, objective-c

Basically, I need to call a method in my AppDelegate from one of my view controller classes.

Currently, I'm doing the following:

`myAppDelegate *appDelegate = (myAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];`

`[appDelegate doMethod];`

And including the myAppDelegate.h at the top of the .m file of the class:

`#import "myAppDelegate.h"`

When I run it, everything works...

But I get the following warning:

`warning 'myAppDelegate' may not respond to '-doMethod'`

Is there another way that I should reference the app delegate?

Thanks for any help in advance.

***EDIT: FIXED:***

All I had to do was declare the method in the .h file of the AppDelegate:

`-(void)doMethod;`

Comment: what is in your myAppDelegate.h?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

adding to Marks comment. Is the `-(void) doMethod;` declared in the appDelegate header file and is the appDelegate.h file imported in the file you try to call the method from:)

Sorry should have put it in as an answer in the first place, so the question does not look unanswered :/